# Use vuex (v3) together with composition-api in nuxt-bridge

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex, vue-composition-api, nuxt-bridge

I have upgraded a nuxt 2 project to nuxt-bridge and I have to rewrite some components.
I want to use the (core) vue composition api and my old vuex store.

I've had things like: `import { mapActions, mapGetters, mapState } from 'vuex'` and my vuex is on version `^v3.0.1`. I wanted to upgrade to v4 but I failed so far, because with nuxt3 it would be so much easier and I am not sure if I can combine nuxt 2.17 with vuex 4, to make use of things like: `import { useStore } from 'vuex'`

Is it possible to use nuxt-bridge, the composition-api and vuex together?
Otherwise I might have to consider to fully upgrade to nuxt3.

What would you advise?

Comment: I would really like an answer to this as well!! Seems like a huge gaping hole in Nuxt Bridge...

Comment: Btw: I ended up upgrading to nuxt3. :S